# Which cycles rendering pass is antialiased

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers, antialiasing

In all render passes that Blender Cycles support, which one are antialiased and which one is not by default. And, if possible, how can I turn all the anti-aliasing for all of them completely? I got know before that Mist passed is anti-aliasing, Z-buffer is not (correct me if I'm wrong).

Here are the list of the other render passes:

Diffuse Direct, Indirect, Color

Glossy Direct, Indirect, Color

Transmission Direct, Indirect, Color

Subsurface Direct, Indirect, Color

Emission

Environment

Shadow

Ambient Occlusion

Normal

Vector

Object Index

Material Index

Comment: What do you mean "turn them all off" ? Do you want to turn off anti-aliasing on it?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean to turn off anti-aliasing for all the passes (if they are on by default).

Comment: For reference, I wrote an answer here about which passes are antialiased. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67229/to-what-degree-does-cycles-sample-level-impact-other-passes/67470#67470 The answer @Crantisz posted on this question is a good summary of how to bypass AA in Cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know, that there is nonstandard algorithm to get anti-aliasing in cycles instead normal render. Each pass in cycles also is an anti-aliasing pass too. Each pass specifies the color, shadow and antialiasing at same time:

[image]

And cycles has a setting to manipulate how far each pixel sample can deviate to get anti-aliasing:

[image]

Making the filter size value smaller will squeeze the samples more into the center. So there is no option to turn off anti-aliasing, but you can make filter size at minimum to get similar result:

[image]